# How to close the gap between drawer and main content in app-drawer-layout in Polymer 2.x?

Tags: polymer, polymer-2.x, polymer-2.0

I have an `app-drawer-layout` element and in it, I want the drawer content (blue) flush with the main content (yellow) with no gap (white) in between them. Note that I changed the `--app-drawer-width` to `100px` from its default `256px`. This might be what is causing the gap. Is this a bug? Or am I coding it wrong?

[Here is the JSBin.](http://jsbin.com/lulenamavo/edit?html,output) *Note: When viewing the demo, make sure the output pane is slid wide enough to make the drawer visible. If the output pane is too narrow, the drawer will be hidden.*

app-drawer-layout

[image]

http://jsbin.com/lulenamavo/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <base href="http://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer-element.html">
  <link rel="import" href="app-layout/app-layout.html">

</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="my-el">
    <template>
      <style>
        app-drawer {
          --app-drawer-width: 100px;
          --app-drawer-content-container: {
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
          }
        }
        #main-content {
          background-color: yellow;
          height: 100vh;
          width: 100vw; /* doesn't make content sections flush */
        }
      </style>
      <app-drawer-layout fullbleed>
        <app-drawer slot="drawer">
          drawer content
        </app-drawer>
        <div id="main-content">
          main content
        </div>
      </app-drawer-layout>
    </template>
    <script>
      class MyEl extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
          return 'my-el'
        }
      }
      customElements.define(MyEl.is, MyEl);
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <my-el></my-el>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a bug. Probably, you missed to read the **NOTE** in the [documentation](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/app-layout/elements/app-drawer).

> **NOTE**:* If you use with and specify a value for `--app-drawer-width`,
>   that value must be accessible by both elements. This can be done by
>   defining the value on the `:host` that contains (or `html` if outside a
>   shadow root):
>
> `:host { --app-drawer-width: 300px; }`

In this case, it would be:

```
<style>
  :host {
    --app-drawer-width: 100px;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

[For clarity, here is the fully coded solution demo.](http://jsbin.com/jodifafuqa/edit?html,output)

http://jsbin.com/jodifafuqa/edit?html,output

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>

  <base href="http://polygit.org/polymer+:master/components/">
  <link rel="import" href="polymer/polymer-element.html">
  <link rel="import" href="app-layout/app-layout.html">

</head>

<body>
  <dom-module id="my-el">
    <template>
      <style>
        :host {
          --app-drawer-width: 100px;
        }
        app-drawer {
          --app-drawer-content-container: {
            background-color: blue;
            color: white;
          }
        }
        #main-content {
          background-color: yellow;
          height: 100vh;
          width: 100vw; /* doesn't make content sections flush */
        }
      </style>
      <app-drawer-layout fullbleed>
        <app-drawer slot="drawer">
          drawer content
        </app-drawer>
        <div id="main-content">
          main content
        </div>
      </app-drawer-layout>
    </template>
    <script>
      class MyEl extends Polymer.Element {
        static get is() {
          return 'my-el'
        }
      }
      customElements.define(MyEl.is, MyEl);
    </script>
  </dom-module>

  <my-el></my-el>
</body>

</html>
```